# Code to count how many integers are strictly larger than all the integers to their right using python

Tags: python, arrays

Given the list of integers, X,
https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TjeNYpZ_PbdBISlJPF-_WqULBc1WpuYthLClovjB3Rs/edit?usp%3Dsharing&sa=D&ust=1594968749928000&usg=AFQjCNG8bAv1lX8pXr4CYcgaDfYFxcbgCg

I want to write code to count how many integers are strictly larger than all the integers to their right excluding the last digit since it doesn’t have a number to its right. E.g. for [2,3,1] the answer should be 1 while for [12,4,4,2,2,3] the answer is 2. I have no clue how to write the code. I will appreciate any guidance on how to proceed.

Comment: Please don't give a link to aGDoc share a example here, All needed info should appear on this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that does that in O(N), where N is the size of the list.

```
l = [12,4,4,2,2,3]

def max_so_far(l):
    m = 0
    for i in l[::-1]: 
        m = max(m, i)
        yield m

sum([x>y for x,y in zip(l[-2::-1], max_so_far(l))])
```

Comment: what does the l represent here, the list X. or is the small X supposed to be the list? Sorry just struggling to get your solution.

Comment: NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: @Sonji - 'l' is given in the question. I added it to my code as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about this code?

```
mylist = list(map(int,input().split()))
count = 0

for i,item in enumerate(mylist): 
    if i == len(mylist) - 1: #here we excluded the last element for a check
        break

    check = max(mylist[i+1:])
    if check < item:
        count = count + 1    

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am understating this problem in two way:

```
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_number)):
        for j in range(i, len(list_of_number)):
           if list_of_number[j] > list_of_number[i]:
               counter += 1
```

Here, after it gets the first value, it scans all the list. The code that follow it will check only the number's right neighbour

```
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_number)-1):
        if list_of_numbers[i+1] > list_of_numbers[i]:
            counter +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def counter(L):
    return sum([1 for i in range(len(L)-1) if L[i] < L[i+1]])
```

Comment: this check if the left one is grater than the right one, shouldn't it be in reversed order or with the less than sign?

Comment: My bad! :( edited.