# What could be causing my code to give wrong answers?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am curious as to why my code is providing the wrong answer in reference to this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948003/code-to-count-how-many-integers-are-strictly-larger-than-all-the-integers-to-the), whereas if I make my own list it gives the correct answer.
below is my code
and here's the [LIST](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TjeNYpZ_PbdBISlJPF-_WqULBc1WpuYthLClovjB3Rs/edit) to be tested

```
X = [12,4,4,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,1]
count = 0
#j is the second element
#it's like i+1
j = 1

for i in range(len(X)-1):
    if j == len(X):
        break
    if (X[i]>X[j]) == True:
        count+=1
    j += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to minimally edit your code to make it output the same answer as the Stack Overflow post you have linked. My solution is below. Additionally, I have commented on the source of error. Your solution only works because in the list you provided each integer which is greater than the integer directly to the right is also strictly greater than all integers to the right; your code counts these integers which are greater than the integer to the right:

```
##### YOUR SOLUTION

X = #list
count = 0
j = 1
for i in range(len(X)-1):

    # This if condition evaluates to true if you are observing the last digit.
    # "Is the last digit greater than all digits to the right?"
    # This is trivial.
    if j == len(X):
        break

    # Is a number greater than the number immediately to the right?
    # (This does not consider all the numbers to the right, only the one directly next to it.)
    if (X[i]>X[j]) == True:
        count+=1

    # j will be each index [0, len(X) - 1] EXACTLY ONCE, not the correct behavior.
    j += 1

print(count)


##### MY SOLUTION

count = 0
j = 1
for i in range(len(X)-1):

    # Set j to be the index one greater than i
    j = i + 1

    # While, for an integer i, there exists more digits to the right.
    while j < len(X):

        # If any integer after i greater than or equal to i ...
        if X[i] <= X[j]:
            break

        # increment j
        j += 1

    # If we got to the last integer without finding an integer greater than i
    # then j now points to one index greater than those in list and increment count
    if j == len(X):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to answer the solution to the question present in the link you posted is as follows -

```
X = [12,4,4,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,1]
count = 0

for i in range(len(X)-1): # This will loop till len(X) - 1
    flag = 0
    for j in range(i+1,len(X)): # For each element, check if it is greater than all elements on right 
        if X[j] >= X[i]:
            flag = 1
            break
    # If above condition inside for loop never passes, we can increase the count :)
    if flag == 0:
        count+=1

print(count)
```

**OUTPUT  :**

```
3
```

The above solution will check every number succeeding the current number. In your solution, your logic was incorrect. You were checking each number with only the next succeeding number. But you have to check it with every succeeding number on the right(and not only 1).

There's a `O(N)` solution to the problem as well which is more efficient than this one. You should refer to the link you have posted in the question for O(N) solution if you are looking for a more optimized one. But, the above code is the correct way of doing it in a naive manner.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No, I couldn't have done that. In the for loop, I first had to check through all elements first and only if none of them passed the loop condition then only run the outer if. For that, using flag was essential

Comment: aha, I understand my mistake, thanks.
then why was it working? coincidence i suppose.

Comment: @EmmanuelManoloSiame In your list, your code passed three checks - `12 > 4`, `4 > 2` and `3 > 1` but it was just coincidence that the correct answer was 3 as well. In other cases, your code would have produced an incorrect answer.